# jquery multiple, variable height divs, show and hide

Tags: jquery, variables, height, html

I cannot seem to get this. Everyone else examples  or questions use different functions or are not variable height. In addition, they are all the same class so my other issue is adding id's to this mess....That being said Im very stuck. Ill take any advice I can get. Thank you for you help.

```
  $(function(){
    var slideHeight = 36; // px
    var defHeight = $('.jswrap').height();
    if(defHeight >= slideHeight){
        $('.jswrap').css('height' , slideHeight + 'px');
        $('.jsreadmore').append('<a href="#">Read More</a>');
        $('.jsreadmore a').click(function(){
            var curHeight = $('.jswrap').height();
            if(curHeight == slideHeight){
                $('.jswrap').animate({
                  height: defHeight
                }, "normal");
                $('.jsreadmore a').html('Close');
            }else{
                $('.jswrap').animate({
                  height: slideHeight
                }, "normal");
                $('.jsreadmore a').html('Read More');
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
    });
```

**Markup:**

```
<div class="jscontainer">
  <h4>title</h4>
      <div class="jswrap">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="jscontainer">
  <h4>title2</h4>
      <div class="jswrap">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

[here is the problem](http://www.doctorhtiller.com/procedures.html)

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: I click to open the first div and they all open. I only posted one of them in the html markup… my fault. All the other divs would be roughly the same though.

Comment: here it is in full force: (not my choice of content but…)
http://www.doctorhtiller.com/procedures.html

Comment: you are not using any specified targeting - this is all that is really missing. See my updated answer below for a demo which I hope will clarify things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/5VdBk/?

Does it need to work with multiple slides?

**Edit**
*after noticed edit to question mentioning multiple slides:*

Updated version which should handle multiple slides of varying content size
http://jsfiddle.net/5VdBk/1/

Comment: yes but there should be multiple divs that open and close. I can target things just fine in css… everything I try to do in JS breaks things.. thanks for your help

Comment: @Jeremey, did you see the second link in my answer? It has multiple div's working there. I've changed this about because I didn't have your CSS but the theory should be easily transferable. Do you still have the issue?

Comment: That would be it!! Thank you. So you just added the "each" and then the ".next().children('a')" to target the anchors of the divs? This doesnt require using id's either?

Comment: changed a little more than that but effectively since you need to get the slide that corresponds to the click element you can use positional selectors (like next()). You'll notice the source of you page has 4 jsreadmore divs instead of 2. I'd go for my implementation which is slightly neater -let me know if I can help integrating it!

Comment: flippen hell, just reloaded your page and see it's working already! That was quick!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a problem: defHeight is euqal to 20 and so the first if is always false and nothing happens because defHeight >= slideHeight is always false.

When you get that right you should not do this:

```
  $('.jsreadmore a').click(function(){
```

but this

```
  $('.jsreadmore a').live('click', (function(){
```

because the 'a' is appended after the dom is created and to bind events on newly created elements you need to use live

Look ath this basic fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FmzBP/1/

Comment: How do you know defHeight is 20? I do not see enough information in the post to make that determination.

Comment: I don't think this is a safe assumption to make; additionally you don't need to use live because you are binding the event after the element is added (albeit after the dom is created).

Comment: The only think im seeing as defined is the slideheight. If im looking at the same thing you are. The defHeight should be controlled by the .jswrap div… right?